# Graphics error while knitting from Rmarkdown to PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a Rmarkdown file that uses 3 libraries: `extrafont`,`ggplot2`,`dplyr`. I have to generate a PDF after knitting this document. But it gives me an error as below:

```
Quitting from lines 21-52 (A6.3.Rmd) 
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid font type
Calls: <Anonymous> ... drawDetails -> drawDetails.text -> grid.Call.graphics
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

This is not the case when I knit to HTML. It works fine.

Below is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,2,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,1.5,2,2,2,2,1.5,2.5,3,3,3,3,5.5,5,6,5.5,7)
                 ,y = c(2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,3.5,3.5,2,3,3.5,4,2.5,3,3,4,3.5)
                 )

# helper dataframe for axis
df_arrow <- data.frame(x = c(0, 0),
                       y = c(0, 0),
                       xend = c(0, 8),
                       yend = c(8, 0)) 


ggplot(df,aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "blue", size = 5)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:7, expand = expansion(add = c(0, 1)))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:7, expand = expansion(add = c(0, 1)))+
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 7), ylim = c(0, 7), clip = "off")+
  geom_segment(data = df_arrow, aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y, yend = yend), size = 0.75, colour = "black",
               arrow = arrow(angle = 20, length = unit(3, "mm"), ends = "last", type = "closed"), linejoin = "mitre") +
  annotate("text", x = c(7.8, 0.3), y = c(0.3, 7.8), label = c("italic(x)", "italic(y)"), parse = TRUE, size = 6,  family = "Arial Narrow")+
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray80"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(1, "mm"),
        text = element_text(size = 18,  family = "Arial Narrow"))
```

And also there are 2 more similar blocks that give slightly different plots.

Not sure if it is with this `extrafont` library that I'm working with.

when I inspect this error it is with this code block that it specifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `family = "Arial Narrow"`

If you remove `family = "Arial Narrow"` in these two lines:

1. `annotate("text", x = c(7.8, 0.3), y = c(0.3, 7.8), label = c("italic(x)", "italic(y)"), parse = TRUE, size = 6,  family = "Arial Narrow")+`
2. `text = element_text(size = 18,  family = "Arial Narrow"))`

The knitting to pdf will work:

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks for that but I now get this error: `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character âˆ’ (U+2212)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.`